# Opensearch disable ssl/https but not SecurityPlugin

Tags: opensearch

it is possible now disable ssl/https but not SecurityPlugin itself?

Previously, in docker-compose, I could do this simply by disabling "`plugins.security.ssl.http.enabled=false`". Now I install using helm and it doesn't work. OpenSearch wants aalways certificate.

I've been trying different options for a few hours now.
"`DISABLE_SECURITY_PLUGIN=true`" - Disabling security completely is not an option for me.

I get always following error.

```
Likely root cause: OpenSearchException[plugins.security.ssl.transport.keystore_filepath or plugins.security.ssl.transport.server.pemcert_filepath and plugins.security.ssl.transport.client.pemcert_filepath must be set if transport ssl is requested.]
```

My

```
  opensearch.yml: |
    cluster.name: opensearch-cluster
    network.host: 0.0.0.0
    plugins:
      security:
        ssl:
          transport:
            enabled: false
            enforce_hostname_verification: false
          http:
            enabled: false
        allow_unsafe_democertificates: false
        allow_default_init_securityindex: true
        audit.type: internal_opensearch
        enable_snapshot_restore_privilege: true
        check_snapshot_restore_write_privileges: true
        restapi:
          roles_enabled: ["all_access", "security_rest_api_access"]
        system_indices:
          enabled: true
          indices:
            [
              ".opendistro-alerting-config",
              ".opendistro-alerting-alert*",
              ".opendistro-anomaly-results*",
              ".opendistro-anomaly-detector*",
              ".opendistro-anomaly-checkpoints",
              ".opendistro-anomaly-detection-state",
              ".opendistro-reports-*",
              ".opendistro-notifications-*",
              ".opendistro-notebooks",
              ".opendistro-asynchronous-search-response*",
            ]
```

Comment: Have you seen https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/install-and-configure/install-opensearch/docker/#sample-docker-compose-file-for-development ?

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Not. But this is not more relevant. I will not use OpenSearch.

Answer (score 3):

[According to the documentation](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security/configuration/tls/), there is no `plugins.security.ssl.transport.enable` option and TLS is mandatory for the transport layer. So you can copy values from [helm chart](https://github.com/opensearch-project/helm-charts/blob/72078b10070c44e560f78119d79b3930e2013b79/charts/opensearch/values.yaml#L63-L67). In this case you need also set option `plugins.security.ssl.allow_unsafe_democertificates` to `true` for the default certificates to work. The final config looks like the following:

```yaml
  opensearch.yml: |
    cluster.name: opensearch-cluster
    network.host: 0.0.0.0
    plugins:
      security:
        ssl:
          transport:
            pemcert_filepath: esnode.pem
            pemkey_filepath: esnode-key.pem
            pemtrustedcas_filepath: root-ca.pem
            enforce_hostname_verification: false
          http:
            enabled: false
        allow_unsafe_democertificates: true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not using opensearch/elasticsearch anymore. Too much inconvinient things and troubles with configurations.

Comment: @JDev what else did you change it for?

Comment: FWIW, there's `plugins.security.ssl.transport.enabled` but it `... must be set to 'true'` (as per startup error).

Comment: how would you set these using a docker-compose.yml? is it possible?

Comment: is it  plugins.security.ssl.allow_unsafe_democertificates or   plugins.security.allow_unsafe_democertificates?